# Updating a initialised Material UI input field react is not updating the value of the input, instead label overlaps the initialised value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-functional-component

[initialise with value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeCur.png)

[after updating the formData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrqiL.png)

I am updating the object just as i am fetching values from. I have checked formData is updated but input does not get updated

```
<Grid item md={6}>
    <FormControl fullWidth={true} disabled={true}>
        <InputLabel>Lat</InputLabel>
        <Input required={true} type={'number'}
            value={formData?.geometry?.location?.lat}/>
    </FormControl>
</Grid>
<Grid item md={6}>
    <FormControl fullWidth={true} disabled={true}>
        <InputLabel>Long</InputLabel>
        <Input required={true} type={'number'}
            value={formData?.geometry?.location?.lng}/>
    </FormControl>
</Grid>
```